# Javascript NaN Concept

Tags: javascript, nan

```js
console.log(isNaN('hello'))
```

Output = true

```js
console.log(Number.isNaN('hello'))
```

Output = false

I don't understand why I am getting **[false]** here. Can anyone please help me understand the concept between these two?

Answer (score 1):

> The Number.isNaN() method determines whether the passed value is NaN and its type is Number.
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/isNaN

The value "hello" does not have a type of Number, so `Number.isNaN` will return false.

> if the value hello does not have a type number, what happens if I pass a number instead of Hello ... console.log(Number.isNaN(1234)) because the type of 1234 is number

If you pass in 1234, it will have the type Number, but will not be NaN, so again `Number.isNaN` will return false.

The only cases where it will return true are if you literally pass it NaN or something that would lead to it:

```
Number.isNaN(NaN) // true
Number.isNaN(0/0) // true
Number.isNaN(1/0) // false (javascript defines 1/0 === Infinity, which is a Number)
```

Comment: if the value hello does not have a type number, what happens if I pass a number instead of Hello ... console.log(Number.isNaN(1234)) because the type of 1234 is number ...

Comment: Responded in the answer above

Answer (score 0):

this functions has `different implementations`. `Number.isNaN` is `more strict` and you will only get `true` for `NaN` values

```
Number.isNaN(NaN); // true
Number.isNaN(Number.NaN); // true
Number.isNaN(0 / 0) // true
```